# Black-Scholes Equation with dividend

Tags: black-scholes, mathematics, finance-mathematics

Consider a European option with payoff $$g(S_T) = S_T^{-5}e^{10S_T}$$ Assume that the interest rate is $r = .1$ and the underlying asset satisfies $S_0 = 2, \sigma = .2$, an pays dividend at continuous rate equal to $q(t,S_t) = qS_t$ and $q = .2$

a.) Write the Black-Scholes equation for this problem.

b.) Solve the problem analytically by the method of separation of variables. Plug into the equation a solution candidate of the form $e^{a\tau}S^{-5}e^{10S}$ and determine $a$.

Attempted solution for a.) The Black-Scholes model with dividend is given by the SDE $$dS_t = S_t(r - q(t,S_t))dt + \sigma S_t dB_t$$ and the Black-Scholes equation is given by $$\begin{cases} \partial_\tau V(\tau,S) &= \frac{\sigma^2 S^2}{2}\partial_{SS} V(\tau,S) + (r - q(t,S))S \partial_S V(\tau,S) - rV(\tau,S)\\
V(\tau,0) &= e^{-r\tau}g(0)\\
V(0,S) &= g(S)
\end{cases}$$
thus with the parameters above we have $$\begin{cases} \partial_{\tau}V(\tau,S) &= \frac{(.2)^2(2)^2}{2}\partial_{S S}V(\tau,S) + (.1 - 2(.2))2V(\tau,S) - .1V(\tau,S)\\
V(\tau,0) &= e^{-.1\tau}g(0) = 0\\
V(0,S) &= g(2) = 2^{-5}e^{20}
\end{cases}$$

A tad confused about b.). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Also, if anyone can check part a.) solution that would be great.

Comment: Those are not difficult questions. Try to work them out yourself will be better for you, in particular, for your PhD thesis later on. If your text book is not clear, try some other books as well, for example, the book "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II" by Shreve, which is pretty readable.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will

Comment: For (b), both $\tau$ and $T$ appeared in $e^{a\tau}S^{-5}e^{10S_T}$. Is it a typo? Why do you need the $\tau$?

Comment: It could be a typo but I am not sure

Comment: I think its safe to assume it is a typo

Comment: @Gordon any chance you could help me here?

Comment: Can you let me know what the $\tau$ in $e^{a\tau}S^{-5}e^{10S_T}$ should be? If the question is not clear, then it is difficulty to answer.

Comment: @Gordon I will ask my professor now

Comment: @Gordon Here is what my professor said: $\tau$ is time-to-maturity $T - t$. There are two ways to write the PDE; 1. by variable $\tau$, 2. by variable $t$. In transformation of these two cases into each other are obtained by the following: partial derivative of $V$ with respect to $\tau$ = negative partial derivative of $V$ with respect to $t$. Other partial derivatives remain unchanged. Hope that clears it up...

Comment: @Gordon is part a.) correct?

Comment: What I do not understand is that why $\tau$ and $T$ appear at the same time. I do not know the back ground, for example, what is (3.22). Please discuss with your professor, TA, or classmates.

Comment: @Gordon my professor edited the exercise as you can see now there is no $T$. I tried to ask the question of what you were concerned with but that was the response I got back. Let me know if there is anything else that needs to be cleared up. Sorry

Comment: (3.22) was the equation I presented sorry was a mistype

Comment: In you payoff $g(S_T)$, why $t$ and $T$ appear at the same time?

Comment: sorry another error my professor made in his lecture notes, just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align*}
V(t, S_t) = E\Big(e^{-r(T-t)} g(S_T)\mid \mathcal{F}_t \Big)
\end{align*}
be the risk-neutral value at time $t$ of the option payoff $g(S_T)$. Then $\{e^{-rt}V(t, S_t), 0 \le t \le T\}$ is a martingale. Consequently,
\begin{align}
-rV + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (r-q)S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S_t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_t^2} = 0,\tag{1}
\end{align}
which is the Black-Scholes equation for the solution.

For a solution of the form
\begin{align*}
V(t, S_t) = e^{a(T-t)}S_t^{-5}e^{10S_t}.
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} &= -a V, \\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial S_t} &= \Big(-\frac{5}{S_t}+10\Big) V,\ \mbox{ and}\\
\frac{\partial V^2}{\partial S_t^2} &= \frac{5}{S_t^2}V + \Big(-\frac{5}{S_t}+10\Big)^2 V\\
&=\Big(\frac{30}{S_t^2} - \frac{100}{S_t} + 100\Big) V.
\end{align*}
Substitute into Equation (1) and evaluate at $t=0$, 
\begin{align*}
-r-a +(r-q)(-5+10S_0) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \big(30-100 S_0 + 100 S_0^2\big) = 0.
\end{align*}
That is
\begin{align*}
a &= -r+(r-q)(-5+10S_0) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \big(30-100 S_0 + 100 S_0^2\big)\\
&= -0.1+ (0.1-0.2)\times (-5+10\times 2) + 0.5 \times 0.2^2 \times (30-100 \times 2 + 100 \times 4)\\
&=3. 
\end{align*}
Finally, the option value is given by
\begin{align*}
V(0, S_0) &= e^{a(T-0)}S_0^{-5}e^{10S_0}\\
&= \cdots 
\end{align*}
Please fill-in here. What is $T$?

Comment: Thank you for your patience I will ask my professor what $T$ is and get back to you

Comment: I will leave the specific calculations for you to fill-in.

Comment: So, is my part a.) of the solution incorrect?